# Gradle + Dagger2

Tags: java, android, gradle, dagger2

Читаю tutorial по `Dagger2`, и возник вопрос, там сказано, что в `root` `build.gradle` нужно добавить:

```
dependencies {
     // other classpath definitions here
     classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
 }
```

Где именно находится `root` `build.gradle`? Это `build.bradle`, который Project?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В корневой элемент файла build.gradle на вашем скриншоте. (Project)

Comment: @DimXenon А еще такой вопрос, там в этом файле написано в  dependencies:" NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong  in the individual module build.grade files", добавление туда  "classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8' " - не повлечет ли за собой каких-то проблем?

Comment: Если там так написано, то вариант остаётся только с файлом для конкретного приложения (app) - добавьте в него, вместо файла всего проекта.

Comment: В принципе, могут потенциально(!) возникнуть некоторые неудобства при добавлении в проектный build.graddle. Но на то в нём и предупреждение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Напишу решение к которому пришла, возможно кому-то еще тоже пригодится:

1) Можно добавить в root `build.grade`, в dependencies:  `classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'` , даже не смотря на предупреждение, что туда нельзя добавлять.

2) Либо можно добавить в `app/build.gradle` такие строчки кода:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // the latest version of the android-apt plugin
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```